# Replace values within dataframe with filename while importing using read.table (R)

Tags: r, string, loops, replace, lapply

I am trying to clean up some data in R. I have a bunch of .txt files: each .txt file is named with an ID (e.g. ABC001), and there is a column (let's call this *ID_Column*) in the .txt file that contains the same ID. Each column has 5 rows (or less - some files have missing data). However, some of the files have incorrect/missing IDs (e.g. ABC01). Here's an image of what each file looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyXfV.png

What I am trying to do here is to import everything AND replace the *ID_Column* with the filename (which I know to all be correct).

Is there any way to do this easily? I think this can probably be done with a for loop but I would like to know if there is any other way. Right now I have this:

```
all_files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_files, read.table, header=TRUE))
```

So, basically, I want to know if it is possible to use lapply (or any other function) to replace *data$ID_Column* with the filenames in *all_files*. I am having trouble as each filename is only represented once in *all_files*, while each *ID_Column* in *data* is represented 5 times (but not always, due to missing data). I think the solution is to create a function and call it within lapply, but I am having trouble with that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just make a function that uses `read.table` and adds the file's name as a column.

```
all_files <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(all_files, function(x){
    a = read.table(x, header=TRUE); 
    a$ID_Column=x 
    return(a)
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great! However, I have just one more problem: it doesn't work if I have files that have no data inside (i.e. 0 rows - only the header is present).

Comment: I pressed 'enter' before I finished commenting, but I can't edit the above comment. Here is my full comment:

Thanks! That works great! However, I have just one more problem: it doesn't work if I have files that have no data inside (i.e. 0 rows - only the header is present). Is there any way to built that in as well, or is it easier to just remove all the 'empty' files beforehand?

Sorry, I'm rather new to R. Thanks again!

Comment: Try adding an `if (nrow(x) == 0) return(NULL)` to the function.

Comment: This works, except that it should be nrow(a) instead of nrow(x).

Comment: I pressed 'enter' before finishing again!

I meant to thank you - thank you for your help!